# Relação entre bean e view

Tags: java, jsf, spring, java-bean

Tenho três `views` que mostram a mesma tabela com uma sequência de leds e informações, tenho uma classe `service` que faz a lógica de negócio para saber qual led e qual cor mostrar, em meu `bean` responsável pela view eu recebo esse método com as informações prontas e passo para os componentes do `view` que mostram o led.

Minha dúvida é, vale a pena (ou, está correto) criar um `bean` específico para essa tabela de leds e usa-lo para referencia-la nas três `views`? Levando em consideração que terei uma redução de código e duplicidade.

Acredito que a forma de implementação e o que é feito nessas telas devem ser levados em conta, porém essa tabela de led específica sempre mostra as mesmas informações decorrente da leitura de dados externos, ela não é alterada a menos que o processo todo comece outra vez, com a coleta de novos dados. 
Não sei se existe uma relação que diz que uma `view` está para apenas um `bean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remover duplicidade é importante, principalmente na fase de projeto ou desenvolvimento, porque depois que o programa é lançado o custo pode ser muito alto e dificulta bastante a manutenção.

Num programa pequeno você pode argumentar que isto é questão de opinião, mas se você já trabalhou em qualquer projeto com complexidade razoável deve saber que no final o produto vai acabar com inconsistências quando alguém alterar uma ou outra parte duplicada. Além disso, num projeto sério, você ainda teria que duplicar testes e vários outros elementos relativos ao que está duplicado.

Claro que é preciso ter bom senso e não tentar abstrair demais o código, mas se é verdadeira a afirmação de que as três telas realmente mostram a mesma informação, então evitar duolicidades é uma boa prática bem objetiva.

Além de fazer isto no lado do Java, faça o mesmo na view, ou seja, crie um componente único que pode ser incluído nas três telas, de tal forma que alterações na tabela seja algo exclusivo dos componentes relacionados à ela e as demais telas e componentes não precisem se acoplar ao modo de funcionamento de tal tabela.

Algo que ajuda é pensar em termos de componentes. Uma boa prática para criar componentes reutilizáveis em geral é sempre usá-los como uma caixa preta, como se você estivesse importando um componente de terceiros. Isto consiste em aplicar bem encapsulamento, escondendo ao máximo o funcionamento interno, e expondo somente os pontos de integração ou extensão necessários.

Comment: Exatamente, coloquei essa parte da view dentro de um include já para não ficar recriando. Ideia era realmente não duplicar código, obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo esse artigo [manged beans, não complique, simplifique](http://www.rponte.com.br/2009/08/27/managed-beans-nao-complique-simplifique/), mas também vou dar minha opinião.

Se você garantir que será sempre o mesmo em todas as páginas, e que nada de nenhuma das páginas poderá interferir nessa tabela, é uma opção boa pra evitar copiar e colar código.

Existem opiniões bem diferentes sobre quantidade de managed beans, quantidade de managed beans por páginas... Na minha opinião, existem boas práticas, mas uma regra que valha pra todas as situações eu não acredito que exista.

Comment: obrigado pelo link, realmente muito interessante